# Creating a shortcode in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Hello I'm trying to turn a function into a shortcode. I've read how to create a shortcode however, when I turn my function into a shortcode I get a different output.

Basically whenever you click on an area of focus all teachers associated with that area will show .

The code below works perfectly.

```
<?php $schools = $post->ID; // the current post id ?>

    <?php
    $args = array( 
        'post_type' => 'teacher',
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key'     => 'areas_of_focus',
                'value'   => $schools,
                'compare' => 'LIKE',
            ),
        ),
    );

    $schools_data_query = new WP_Query($args);

    ?>

    <?php

    if ( $schools_data_query->have_posts() ) {
        echo '<ul>';
        while ( $schools_data_query->have_posts() ) {
            $schools_data_query->the_post();
            //echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
            //echo '<li>' . get_permalink() . '</li>'; ?>        
           <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>

    <?php
        }
        echo '</ul>';
    } else {
        // no posts found
    }
```

Now I want to turn it into a shortcode. Here is what I have so far

```
function gm_list_teacher_shortcode($atts){
    $args = array( 
    'post_type' => 'teacher',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'     => 'areas_of_focus',
            'value'   => $schools,
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
        ),
    ),
);

    $schools_data_query = new WP_Query($args);

    global $post;
    $schools = $post->ID;

    $content = '';
    $content .= '<ul>';

        while($schools_data_query->have_posts()) : $schools_data_query->the_post();

        $content .= '<li><a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a></li>';

        endwhile;


    $content .= '</ul>';

    wp_reset_query();

    return $content;
}

add_shortcode('gm_list_teacher', 'gm_list_teacher_shortcode');
```

However when I use this shortcode no matter what area of focus I click on the same teachers show. I believe when creating the shortcode I'm no addressing the following line correctly

```
$schools = $post->ID;
```

Any help would be really appreciated. I'm in no way a great programmer. Thank you

Comment: I would have `$schools = $post->ID` done before you call the array.

Answer (score 0):

Try this I editing this code Please test.

```
function gm_list_teacher_shortcode($atts){
    global $post;
    $schools = $post->ID;
    $args = array( 
    'post_type' => 'teacher',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'     => 'areas_of_focus',
            'value'   => $schools,
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
        ),
    ),
);
    $schools_data_query = new WP_Query($args);
    global $post;
    $schools = $post->ID;
    $content = '';
    $content .= '<ul>';
        while($schools_data_query->have_posts()) : $schools_data_query->the_post();
        $content .= '<li><a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a></li>';
        endwhile;
    $content .= '</ul>';
    wp_reset_query();
    return $content;
}
add_shortcode('gm_list_teacher', 'gm_list_teacher_shortcode');
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, unfortunately I'm getting the same results

Comment: What result getting found ?